# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Scope

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту "PMBOK та PM ISO українською". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

В якості варіантів перекладу Scope розглядаємо такі варіанти:

- Зміст
- Вміст

Варіант "об'єм" відкинули, як занадто "фізичний".
Варіант "обсяг" використовуємо в перекладі таких термінів:

- Earned Value / Освоєний обсяг
- Earned Value Management / Метод освоєного обсягу
- Planned Value / Заплановий обсяг

Є ціла низка термінів, пов'язаних із Scope:

- [Project Scope](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Project_Scope) PMI / ISO)
- [Project Scope Statement](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Project_Scope_Statement) PMI / ISO)
- [Scope Baseline](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Scope_Baseline) PMI)
- [Scope Creep](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Scope_Creep) PMI / ISO)
- [Scope Management Plan](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Scope_Management_Plan) (PMI)

Визначення термінів можна подивитися за посиланнями вище.

Answer (score 1):

- *Межі проєкту*
- *Заявлені межі проєкту*
- *Відлікові межі*
- *Розповзання меж*
- *План ... межами*

Ще можна було б використати *кордони.*

> **[scope](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=scope&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)** [skɘʋp] *n*
> **1.** межі, рамки;
> **2.** масштаб, розмах, сфера, поле (діяльності);
> **3.** можливість, простір, свобода (дій);
> **4.** кінцева мета; задум; основна ідея;

Варіантів хоч греблю гати.